# Eclipse "assign to new local variable" (crtl+2-l) not available for c++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use Eclipse as C++ IDE, because I am used to Eclipse shortcuts in the java world. However using (crtl+2-l) which assigns the result of an expression to a new local variable does not work in the C/C++ perspective. Any idea how I can use this eclipse assistance in C/C++ ? It is really useful when working with unfamiliar APIs, because you can get the result from a function call assigned to a new local variable without even knowing the function's return type.

Comment: Looks like you need C++ `auto` variable.

Comment: That's very unlikely a specific Eclipse-CTD problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to turn your expression into a local variable. Also try right-clicking inside the editor and look what `Refactor` has to offer.

Comment: Crtl + Shift + L just lists all shortcuts but there is no "assign to new local variable" in this list.

Comment: @egelev You are right. It should be ``Alt`` instead of ``Ctrl``. I corrected this in my answer.